# Looping through array forwards and backwards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, loops

I'm currently testing out looping through an array of objects.

The current object is presented in a `ViewController` with next and previous buttons. When next is pressed, the next object in the array should be presented in the view controller. If it is the last object, it should go to the first object in the array. When previous is pressed, it should display the previous object to the current object in the array. If it reaches the first object, it should go to the last object in the array. However, only the next button works, the previous button gets stuck on the first object and I don't know why. The next button works perfectly. Any ideas?

```
- (void)changeObject:(id)sender{

    NSUInteger index = [self.objectArray indexOfObject:self.currentObject];

    UIBarButtonItem *button = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
    NSUInteger nextIndex;

    if([button.title isEqualToString:@"Next Object"]){
        nextIndex = (index + 1) % self.objectArray.count;
    }
    else{
        // Previous Object
        NSLog(@"Previous Object");
        nextIndex = (index - 1) % self.objectArray.count;

        if (nextIndex == -1) {
            nextIndex = self.objectArray.count - 1;
        }
    }

    index = nextIndex;
    self.currentObject = [self.objectArray objectAtIndex:index];

    self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Values", self.currentObject.name];

}
```

**EDIT:** what I ended up doing was the following:

```
- (void)changeObject:(id)sender{

    NSInteger index = [self.objectArray indexOfObject:self.currentObject];

    UIBarButtonItem *button = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

    if([button.title isEqualToString:@"Next Object"]){
        index++;
        if (index >= self.objectsArray.count){
             index = 0;
        }
    }
    else{
        index--;
        if (index < 0){
             index = self.objectsArray.count - 1;
        }
    }

    self.currentObject = [self.objectArray objectAtIndex:index];

    self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Values", self.currentObject.name];

}
```

Comment: You don't want to be taking the modulus when decrementing. Change `nextIndex = (index - 1) % self.objectArray.count;` to `nextIndex = (index - 1);`

Comment: the modulus function in the else part is messing things up. Say `self.objectArray.count == 10` and `index == 0` in which case, your `nextIndex` will try `(0-1)%10 == (-1)%10 == 9` and there would be no case in which it will enter the `if (nextIndex == -1)` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
- (void)changeObject:(id)sender{

    NSInteger index = [self.objectArray indexOfObject:self.currentObject];

    UIBarButtonItem *button = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

    if([button.title isEqualToString:@"Next Object"]){
        index++;
        if (index >= self.objectsArray.count) index = 0;
    }
    else{
        index--;
        if (index < 0) index = self.objectsArray.count - 1;
    }

    self.currentObject = [self.objectArray objectAtIndex:index];

    self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Values", self.currentObject.name];

}
```

Comment: OP wanted this in the else, read post carefully:
    if (index <= 0) index = self.objectsArray.count - 1;

Comment: I think you must have written this before I updated :) already fixed.

Comment: @davidf2281 why? I don't see that.

Comment: Comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false. Causes app to crash. Would `if(index<=-1)` work? I tried it, and nothing  happens. The next function works perfect though :)

Comment: This works but `if (index < 0)` will always return false. It needs to be `if (index == -1)`.

Comment: @JosueEspinosa huh? Doesn't index < 0 return false precisely when the index (which has just been decremented) is less than 0?

Comment: I had that line in xcode, and the statement was never run. I think it runs 0 as a boolean, e.g. `if (index < false)`, which is always false.

Comment: You could change `NSUInteger` to `NSInteger` and it will work.

Comment: I did that. Thank you.